# Extract Date From Long Date - Time Format

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

I have the following dates and time in a column:

```
23 Jul 2016 04:36:37 GMT
24 Jul 2016 07:46:12 GMT
26 Jul 2016 05:44:21 GMT
25 Jul 2016 14:25:39 GMT
20 Jul 2016 15:14:42 GMT
22 Jul 2016 11:52:02 GMT
23 Jul 2016 14:31:31 GMT
23 Jul 2016 11:04:36 GMT
12 Jul 2016 22:33:19 GMT
21 May 2016 20:51:54 GMT
8 Jul 2016 07:38:34 GMT
5 Jun 2016 05:00:29 GMT
```

I would like to get an output in the format MM/DD/YYYY or M/D/Y.

I have tried using the following post as a reference: [Removing time element of Long Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338826/removing-time-element-of-long-date-format)

However, I can not use `=INT(A1)` due to the formatting or `=LEFT(A1,10)` because it may be 10 or 11 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the two:

```
=INT(--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))
```

Since we only need to remove the `GMT` we don't care how long it is we just remove the last three.

[image]

Comment: How about `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))` instead of `INT`?

Comment: @AlexisOlson it works and there is nothing wrong with it, but is more typing.  I tend to try to limit the times my aged fingers need to strike the keyboard. :)

Comment: A couple characters more, but it's much more clear what is going on.

Comment: @ScottCraner just curious, what does the `--` before `LEFT` do in the formula that you posted in the answer?  Brilliant solution, I was going to try and answer but you beat me to it.

Comment: The `--` coerces the string to be a numerical value by taking the negative twice.

Comment: @Namkce In addition to what Alexis just said LEFT,RIGHT and MID return strings.  Doing any mathamatical process on a number stored as a string will return the string as a number.  So we multiply it by -1 * -1 and it becomes a number.  It can be done with a formula VALUE().

Comment: @AlexisOlson 6 in one half dozen in another.  I find this method easier for me.  But I understand your thoughts.  I was mainly building on what the OP started.  Feel free to post yours as an answer.  Even if this OP does not choose yours, latter visitors may find yours easier.

Comment: Hey @ScottCraner, thanks for the neat answer. This works perfectly.

Comment: @pnuts Because...that would be too smart...And I just don't want to.  Or since they just want the date.  Text to columns on the space. Then delete the other two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Scott Craner's answer, you can remove the last the characters ("GMT") and then find the date value as follows:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))
```

Comment: Great. Thanks guys. Please upvote the question when you get a moment.

Comment: does a trailing space really throw off the `DATEVALUE` formula?  `DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,11))` .  If the trailing space does screw it up then insert a `TRIM()` around the `LEFT` formula

Comment: @ForwardEd It doesn't seem to, but if it did you could take off 4 characters from the end instead of 3.

Comment: taking only 11 avoids grabbing all the time, and just leaves the date to deal with.  Mind you the date has to be in a format that DATEVALUE will deal with.  Interesting DATEVALUE will just ignore the time portion in its conversion?

Comment: @ForwardEd - DATEVALUE ignores the time portion, and TIMEVALUE ignores the date portion.